# Ignore rows that do not contain specific text

Tags: perl

How can I ignore rows that do not contain the text `<CNV>` with Perl?

The following code skips rows that contain `<CNV>` and I would like to capture rows that contain `<CNV>`:

```
while ( <$in_fh> ) {

        next if /^#/;
        next if /\b(?:CNV)\b/;

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing the `if` to `unless`? :)

```
...
next unless /\b(?:CNV)\b/;
....
```

Comment: You could also do this with an `if !`.